# socket_connect() - Erro 113 - PHP

Tags: php, socket, arduino

Eu estou tentando fazer um Arduíno receber dados segundo uma estrutura `PHP`. Explicando rapidamente, quando o usuário alterar o status, entre 0 e 1, o mesmo emitiria um sinal para o Arduíno segundo o que fosse escolhido e o Arduíno recebendo esse dado, dependendo dele, ligaria ou desligaria o LED. O código que eu uso no Arduíno é o seguinte:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

//Configurações do Ethernet Shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192,168,0, 101 }; // ip que o arduino assumirá
byte gateway[] = { 192,168,0, 1 };  // ip do roteador
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };

// String que representa o estado dos dispositivos
//char Luz[7] = "0000L#";

EthernetServer server(80); // Cria o servidor na porta 8081

// String onde é guardada as msgs recebidas
char msg[7] = "0000L#";

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();
  //pinMode(A0,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(A1,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(A2,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(A3,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(A4,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(A5,OUTPUT);
  // Configura o pino d13 como saída 
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 EthernetClient client = server.available();
  // SE receber um caracter...
  if (client) {
    // guarda o caracter na string 'msg'
    msg[6] = client.read();

    switch(msg[6]) {
      case 0:
          // Configura o pino 13 como HIGH
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      break;
      case 1:
          // Configura o pino 13 como LOW
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);   
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

E o código em meu arquivo `PHP`, que faz a comunicação com o Arduíno é o seguinte:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    // Se conecta ao IP e Porta:
socket_connect($sock,"192.168.0.101", 80);

if (!socket_connect($sock, "192.168.0.101", 80)){
    die('Socket error : '.socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
}

$msg = 0;

// Executa a ação correspondente ao botão apertado.
if($status == 0) {
    $msg = 0;
    socket_write($sock,$msg,strlen($msg));
} else if($status == 1){
    $msg = 1;
    socket_write($sock,$msg,strlen($msg));
}

//socket_write($sock,'R#',2); //Requisita o status do sistema.

// Caso ele não receba o status corretamente, avisa erro.
//else { echo "Falha ao receber status da casa."; }
socket_close($sock);
```

Quando eu altero o status e o código acima é executado, me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
socket_connect() unable to connect 113 no route to host
```

No caso, tanto o Arduíno quanto meu computador estão conectados a um roteador e o Arduíno "pega" o IP normalmente. Quando eu pingo no Arduíno, eu obtenho resposta normalmente, mas quando executo o código descrito acima, não consigo fazer essa comunicação.

Comment: não conheço arduíno nem php, mas tem uma coisa que me parece estranha: afunção socket_connect está sendo chamada duas vezes, uma em seguida da outra...isso está certo ?

Comment: @zentrunix No caso, a segunda vez que chamo ela é para poder testar a conexão, para ver se tudo está correto ou não e se a conexão não der certo, poder ver qual é o erro, que no caso, é o que está descrito na pergunta.

Comment: acho que deveria ser apenas um connect...mas daria erro 56, não 113...desconfio que depois que você resolver o erro 113 (erro de rota) este erro 56 vai aparecer....um teste simples que você pode fazer com relação ao erro de rota seria fazer um telnet para o arduino "telnet 192.168.0.101  80" e ver se funciona...se **não** funcionar então o erro não é no seu programa, mas sim na configuração de sua rede

Comment: @zentrunix No momento, agora não tenho como fazer esse teste. Assim que fizer dou o retorno. Se caso o erro for na minha rede, como poderia prosseguir para poder solucionar essa questão?